# VB.NET - Downgraded application from .NET 4.0 to .NET 3.5 - Experiencing new error about mscoreei.dll

Tags: vb.net, frameworks

Good afternoon folks!

I'm hoping you can help me troubleshoot an issue I'm having.  I'm working on a VB.NET console application, and everything was all fine and dandy and it ran error free.  But then we discovered that machines which did not have .NET 4.0 installed would not run, because they had .NET 3.5.  We cannot update the framework on those servers, so I tried to downgrade the version of .NET that my application was using.

I made sure all references were at their proper versions and that functionality remained, and I recompiled.  The application now runs perfectly fine for those servers, however one of the newer servers we have that uses .NET 4.0 is now giving an error about a file named MScoreei.dll

The error is as follows...

"Windows Server roles and features cannot be automatically installed by using the Windows Features control panel.

To install Windows Server roles and features, open Server Manager, or use the Server Manager cmdlets for Windows PowerShell.

The following command cannot be executed:
FONDUE.EXE /enable-feature:NetFx3 /caller-name:mscoreei.dll"

My best guess is that the server is unable to emulate a 3.5 environment. I'm hoping someone can give me more direction.

Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

Figured it out.

I had to add the following line to my .config file...

```
<startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0.30319" />
</startup>
```